# Pyspark: explode json in column to multiple columns

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

The data looks like this -

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------------------------+
|         id|      point|                         data|
+-----------------------------------------------------+
|        abc|          6|{"key1":"124", "key2": "345"}|
|        dfl|          7|{"key1":"777", "key2": "888"}|
|        4bd|          6|{"key1":"111", "key2": "788"}|
```

I am trying to break it into the following format.

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|         id|      point|       key1|       key2|
+------------------------------------------------
|        abc|          6|        124|        345|
|        dfl|          7|        777|        888|
|        4bd|          6|        111|        788|
```

The `explode` function explodes the dataframe into multiple rows. But that is not the desired solution.

Note: This solution does not answers my questions.
[PySpark "explode" dict in column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50683894/pyspark-explode-dict-in-column)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

As long as you are using Spark version 2.1 or higher, [`pyspark.sql.functions.from_json`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.from_json) should get you your desired result, but you would need to first define the required `schema`

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_json, col
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType

schema = StructType(
    [
        StructField('key1', StringType(), True),
        StructField('key2', StringType(), True)
    ]
)

df.withColumn("data", from_json("data", schema))\
    .select(col('id'), col('point'), col('data.*'))\
    .show()
```

which should give you

```python
+---+-----+----+----+
| id|point|key1|key2|
+---+-----+----+----+
|abc|    6| 124| 345|
|df1|    7| 777| 888|
|4bd|    6| 111| 788|
+---+-----+----+----+
```

Comment: You should be able to use something the following to extract the schema of the JSON from the data field...  `schema = spark.read.json(df.rdd.map(lambda row: row.data)).schema`

Comment: Is there any way to do this without supplying a schema? In the context of spark streaming jobs, the above schema extraction is not an option @SimonPeacock, writing down the complete schema is .. messy (to say the least) and also quite unflexible as I want additional fields to appear without having to adapt and restart the whole streaming job

Comment: get schema using `df.schema` and don't forget to use all dataTypes as `StringType()` else it may give `null` values for other data types as well as for StringTypes

Comment: In case you want to select all rest of the DF columns and also expan the json column use following `df2 = df.select("*", col("data.*"))`

Answer (score 8):

As suggested by @pault, the data field is a `string` field. since the keys are the same (i.e. 'key1', 'key2') in the JSON string over rows, you might also use `json_tuple()` (this function is New in version **1.6** based on the documentation)

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.select('id', 'point', F.json_tuple('data', 'key1', 'key2').alias('key1', 'key2')).show()
```

Below is **My original post:** which is most likely **WRONG** if the original table is from `df.show(truncate=False)` and thus the `data` field is NOT a python data structure.

Since you have exploded the data into rows, I supposed the column `data` is a Python data structure instead of a string:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.select('id', 'point', F.col('data').getItem('key1').alias('key1'), F.col('data')['key2'].alias('key2')).show()
```

Comment: I don't think this works in this case- you need a `MapType()` column to use `getItem()` but it looks like it's a string here.

Comment: the OP mentioned the results had been exploded into multiple rows, this does not sounds to be a string field.

Comment: *"The explode function explodes the dataframe into multiple rows."* sounds like OP is stating a fact, rather than what they have tried. Also, if it were a `MapType()` it would not display as shown in the post.

Comment: thanks, I think you might be right. but I think it can be much simpler when keys are constant in the JSON strings.

Comment: this works. I did not know about `json_tuple` - it's much easier than defining the schema.

Comment: struggled 1 day with looping, this is really kool.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @jxc, [`json_tuple`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.json_tuple.html) should work fine if you were not able to define the schema beforehand and you only needed to deal with a single level of json string. I think it's more straight forward and easier to use. Strangely, I didn't find anyone else mention this function before.

In my use case, original dataframe schema: `StructType(List(StructField(a,StringType,true)))`, json string column shown as:

```
+---------------------------------------+
|a                                      |
+---------------------------------------+
|{"k1": "v1", "k2": "2", "k3": {"m": 1}}|
|{"k1": "v11", "k3": "v33"}             |
|{"k1": "v13", "k2": "23"}              |
+---------------------------------------+
```

Expand json fields into new columns with `json_tuple`:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = df.select(F.col('a'), 
    F.json_tuple(F.col('a'), 'k1', 'k2', 'k3') \
    .alias('k1', 'k2', 'k3'))

df.schema
df.show(truncate=False)
```

The document doesn't say much about it, but at least in my use case, new columns extracted by `json_tuple` are `StringType`, and it only extract single depth of JSON string.

```
StructType(List(StructField(k1,StringType,true),StructField(k2,StringType,true),StructField(k3,StringType,true)))

+---------------------------------------+---+----+-------+
|a                                      |k1 |k2  |k3     |
+---------------------------------------+---+----+-------+
|{"k1": "v1", "k2": "2", "k3": {"m": 1}}|v1 |2   |{"m":1}|
|{"k1": "v11", "k3": "v33"}             |v11|null|v33    |
|{"k1": "v13", "k2": "23"}              |v13|23  |null   |
+---------------------------------------+---+----+-------+
```

Answer (score 1):

In this approach you just need to set the name of column with Json content.
No need to set up the schema. It makes everything automatically.

```
json_col_name = 'data'
keys = df.select(f"{json_col_name}.*").columns
jsonFields= [f"{json_col_name}.{key} {key}" for key in keys]

main_fields = [key for key in df.columns if key != json_col_name]
df_new = df.selectExpr(main_fields + jsonFields)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for my use case

```
data1 = spark.read.parquet(path)
json_schema = spark.read.json(data1.rdd.map(lambda row: row.json_col)).schema
data2 = data1.withColumn("data", from_json("json_col", json_schema))
col1 = data2.columns
col1.remove("data")
col2 = data2.select("data.*").columns
append_str ="data."
col3 = [append_str + val for val in col2]
col_list = col1 + col3
data3 = data2.select(*col_list).drop("json_col")
```

Answer (score 0):

All credits to  Shrikant Prabhu

You can simply use SQL

```
SELECT id, point, data.*
FROM original_table
```

Like this the schema of the new table will adapt if the data changes and you won't have to do anything in your pipelin.