# Decoding a Column and Extracting Into Several Columns using PySpark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

**Given:** I have the following pySpark Dataframe:

```python
s_df.show(10)

+-------------+--------------------+-------+--------------------+
|    timestamp|               value|quality|          attributes|
+-------------+--------------------+-------+--------------------+
|1506846688201|eyJGbG9vcl9OdW1iZ...|      3|[WrappedArray(0.3...|
|1506846714421|eyJGbG9vcl9OdW1iZ...|      3|[WrappedArray(0.3...|
|1506853046041|eyJGbG9vcl9OdW1iZ...|      3|[WrappedArray(0.3...|
|1506853069411|eyJGbG9vcl9OdW1iZ...|      3|[WrappedArray(0.3...|
|1506853175701|eyJGbG9vcl9OdW1iZ...|      3|[WrappedArray(0.3...|
|1506853278721|eyJWYWx1ZSI6ICJOQ...|      3|[WrappedArray(0.3...|
|1506853285741|eyJWYWx1ZSI6ICJOQ...|      3|[WrappedArray(0.3...|
|1506853313701|eyJWYWx1ZSI6ICJOQ...|      3|[WrappedArray(0.3...|
|1506856544461|eyJJbnNlcnRUaW1lI...|      3|[WrappedArray(0.3...|
|1506856563751|eyJJbnNlcnRUaW1lI...|      3|[WrappedArray(0.3...|
+-------------+--------------------+-------+--------------------+
only showing top 10 rows
```

**Goal:** I want to decode the `value` column and extract the data into a data frame which looks like this:

```python
  Counter  Duration   EventEndTime  ...   Floor_Number     InsertTime Value
0      1.0      2790  1506846690991  ...             NA  1507645527691     0
0      1.0      2760  1506846717181  ...             NA  1507645530751     0
0      1.0      5790  1506853051831  ...             NA  1509003670478    NA
0      1.0      6060  1506853075471  ...             NA  1509003671231    NA
0      1.0      3480  1506853179181  ...             NA  1509003671935    NA
0      1.0      2760  1506853281481  ...             NA  1509004002809    NA
0      1.0      3030  1506853288771  ...             NA  1509004003249    NA
0      1.0      2790  1506853316491  ...             NA  1509004004038    NA
0      1.0      3510  1506856547971  ...             NA  1509003922437    NA
0      1.0      3810  1506856567561  ...             NA  1509003923116    NA
```

**Difficulty:** I can decode but I am unable to extract the `dict` in `pySpark`. I end up doing it in `pandas`. I would like to do all the operations in `pySpark`.

**My Attempt**

I use the following `udf` to decode the `value` column in the following way:

```python
def decode_values(x):
    return base64.b64decode(x)
udf_myFunction = udf(decode_values, StringType())
result = ts_df.withColumn('value', udf_myFunction('value'))
```

to get the following:

```python
result.show(10)

+-------------+--------------------+-------+--------------------+
|    timestamp|               value|quality|          attributes|
+-------------+--------------------+-------+--------------------+
|1506846688201|{"Floor_Number": ...|      3|[WrappedArray(0.3...|
|1506846714421|{"Floor_Number": ...|      3|[WrappedArray(0.3...|
|1506853046041|{"Floor_Number": ...|      3|[WrappedArray(0.3...|
|1506853069411|{"Floor_Number": ...|      3|[WrappedArray(0.3...|
|1506853175701|{"Floor_Number": ...|      3|[WrappedArray(0.3...|
|1506853278721|{"Value": "NA", "...|      3|[WrappedArray(0.3...|
|1506853285741|{"Value": "NA", "...|      3|[WrappedArray(0.3...|
|1506853313701|{"Value": "NA", "...|      3|[WrappedArray(0.3...|
|1506856544461|{"InsertTime": 15...|      3|[WrappedArray(0.3...|
|1506856563751|{"InsertTime": 15...|      3|[WrappedArray(0.3...|
+-------------+--------------------+-------+--------------------+
```

The `value` column appears as a `dict` so I do the following in pandas:

```python
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
result2 = result.toPandas()
final_df = result2.value.apply(json.loads).apply(json_normalize).pipe(lambda x: pd.concat(x.values))
final_df.head()

  Counter  Duration   EventEndTime  ...   Floor_Number     InsertTime Value
0      1.0      2790  1506846690991  ...             NA  1507645527691     0
0      1.0      2760  1506846717181  ...             NA  1507645530751     0
0      1.0      5790  1506853051831  ...             NA  1509003670478    NA
0      1.0      6060  1506853075471  ...             NA  1509003671231    NA
0      1.0      3480  1506853179181  ...             NA  1509003671935    NA
0      1.0      2760  1506853281481  ...             NA  1509004002809    NA
0      1.0      3030  1506853288771  ...             NA  1509004003249    NA
0      1.0      2790  1506853316491  ...             NA  1509004004038    NA
0      1.0      3510  1506856547971  ...             NA  1509003922437    NA
0      1.0      3810  1506856567561  ...             NA  1509003923116    NA
```

I tried to create another `udf` function but it did not work:

```python
def convert_dict_to_columns(x):
     df_out = x.apply(json.loads).apply(json_normalize).pipe(lambda y: pd.concat(y.values))
     return df_out

# Convert the dict to columns
udf_convert_d2c = udf(convert_dict_to_columns, StringType())
final_result = result.withColumn('value', udf_convert_d2c('value'))
```

Any idea how I can do this in a pySpark-y way.

Here's my minimal viable code:

```python
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Timestamp', 'value'])
df.loc[:, 'Timestamp'] = [1501891200, 1501891200, 1501891200, 1501891200, 1501891200, 1501891200]
df.loc[:, 'value'] = [{"Floor_Number": "NA", "Value": 0.0,  "InsertTime": 1507645527691, "EventStartTime": 1506846688201},
                      {"Floor_Number": "NA", "Value": 0.0,  "InsertTime": 1507645527691, "EventStartTime": 1506846688201},
                      {"Floor_Number": "NA", "Value": 0.0,  "InsertTime": 1507645527691, "EventStartTime": 1506846688201},
                      {"Floor_Number": "NA", "Value": 0.0,  "InsertTime": 1507645527691, "EventStartTime": 1506846688201},
                      {"Floor_Number": "NA", "Value": 0.0,  "InsertTime": 1507645527691, "EventStartTime": 1506846688201},
                      {"Floor_Number": "NA", "Value": 0.0,  "InsertTime": 1507645527691, "EventStartTime": 1506846688201}]

 s_df = spark.createDataFrame(df)
```

Comment: You don't need the `udf` for the base64 decode. You can use `pyspark.sql.functions.unbase64` and cast the result to a string. Try: `result = ts_df.withColumn('value', unbase64(col('value')).cast("string"))`. Then you can parse the `json` using `pyspark.sql.functions.from_json`, provided you know the `schema`. Hard to provide a more general and complete solution without a reproducible [mcve].

Comment: Thanks for a quick response. What is variable `col` in the col('value')? I get the error: NameError: name 'col' is not defined

Comment: I created a minimal viable code. The schema is known as you can see in the `value` list. How do I use from_json to convert each row into multiple columns? Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at this post: [Pyspark: explode json in column to multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51070251/pyspark-explode-json-in-column-to-multiple-columns)