# Make JSON in Spark's structured streaming accessible in python (pyspark) as dataframe without RDD

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I use Spark 2.4.3 and want to do structured streaming with data from a Kafka source. The following code works so far:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from ast import literal_eval

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("streamer") \
    .getOrCreate()

# Create DataFrame representing the stream
dsraw = spark.readStream \
  .format("kafka") \
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092") \
  .option("subscribe", "test") \
  .option("startingOffsets", """{"test":{"0":2707422}}""") \
  .load()

# Convert Kafka stream to something readable
ds = dsraw.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")

# Do query on the raw data
rawQuery = dsraw \
     .writeStream \
     .queryName("qraw") \
     .format("memory") \
     .start()
raw = spark.sql("select * from qraw")

# Do query on the converted data
dsQuery = ds \
     .writeStream \
     .queryName("qds") \
     .format("memory") \
     .start()
sdf = spark.sql("select * from qds")

# I have to access raw otherwise I get errors...
raw.select("value").show()

sdf.show()

# Make the json stuff accessable
sdf2 = sdf.rdd.map(lambda val: literal_eval(val['value']))
print(sdf2.first())
```

But I really wonder if the convertion in the next to last line is the most useful/fastest one. Do you have other ideas? Can I stay with (Spark) dataframes instead of the  RDD?

The output of the script is

```
+--------------------+
|               value|
+--------------------+
|{
  "Signal": "[...|
|{
  "Signal": "[...|
+--------------------+
only showing top 20 rows

{'Signal': '[1234]', 'Value': 0.0, 'Timestamp': '2019-08-27T13:51:43.7146327Z'}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some solutions out there but only this adapted solution does work (credit goes to https://stackoverflow.com/a/51070457/3021134):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_json, col
from pyspark.sql.types import StructField, StructType, StringType, DoubleType

schema = StructType(
        [
                StructField("Signal", StringType()),
                StructField("Value", DoubleType()),
                StructField("Timestamp", StringType())
        ]
)

sdf.withColumn("value", from_json("value", schema))\
    .select(col('value.*'))\
    .show()
```

with the output:

```
+--------+-----------+--------------------+
|  Signal|      Value|           Timestamp|
+--------+-----------+--------------------+
|[123456]|        0.0|2019-08-27T13:51:...|
|[123457]|        0.0|2019-08-27T13:51:...|
|[123458]| 318.880859|2019-08-27T13:51:...|
|[123459]|   285.5808|2019-08-27T13:51:...|
```