# How to query a dictionary format column in Pyspark dataframe

Tags: json, dataframe, dictionary, pyspark

There is the following dataframe:

```
  >>> df.printSchema()
  root
   |-- I: string (nullable = true)
   |-- F: string (nullable = true)
   |-- D: string (nullable = true)
   |-- T: string (nullable = true)
   |-- S: string (nullable = true)
   |-- P: string (nullable = true)
```

column F is in dictionary format:

```
   {"P1":"1:0.01","P2":"3:0.03,4:0.04","P3":"3:0.03,4:0.04",...}
```

I need to read column F as following and create two new columns P and N

```
   P1 => "1:0.01"
   P2 => "3:0.03,4:0.04"
   and so on

 +--------+--------+-----------------+-----+------+--------+----+
 | I      |  P     | N               |  D  | T    | S      | P  |
 +--------+--------+---------------- +------------+--------+----+
 | i1     |  p1    | 1:0.01          |  d1 | t1   | s1     | p1 |
 |--------|--------|-----------------|-----|------|--------|----|
 | i1     |  p2    | 3:0.03,4:0.04   |  d1 | t1   | s1     | p1 |
 |--------|--------|-----------------|-----|------|--------|----|
 | i1     |  p3    | 3:0.03,4:0.04   |  d1 | t1   | s1     | p1 |
 |--------|--------|-----------------|-----|------|--------|----|
 | i2     |  ...   | ....            |  d2 | t2   | s2     | p2 |
 +--------+--------+-----------------+-----+------+--------+----+
```

any suggestion in Pyspark?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pyspark: explode json in column to multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51070251/pyspark-explode-json-in-column-to-multiple-columns)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. In the provided link the dictionary only has two keys. Here the dictionary has many keys.

Comment: For this answer, in the link, the schema is provided, which is known beforehand. But in my case the schema cannot be provided. Here it only has two keys, key1 and key2. Mine might have key1, key2, ...., key128 and not a fixed number. How do you provide a flexible schema?

Comment: Also I don't want to add new columns per key BUT new rows. It is more of an "explode".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved this at the end:

```
 #This method replaces "," with ";" to 
 #distinguish between other camas in the string to split it
 def _comma_replacement(val):
    if (val):
        val = val.replace('","', '";"').replace('{','').replace('}', '')
    return val

replacing = UserDefinedFunction(lambda x: _comma_replacement(x))
new_df = df.withColumn("F", replacing(col("F")))
new_df = new_df.withColumn("F",split(col("F"),";").cast(ArrayType(StringType())))
exploded_df = new_df.withColumn("F", explode("F"))
df_sep = exploded_df.withColumn("F",split(col("F"),'":"').cast(ArrayType(StringType())))
dff = df_sep.withColumn("P", df_sep["F"].getItem(0))
dff_new = dff.withColumn("N", dff["F"].getItem(1))
dff_new = dff_new.drop('F')
```

Using another UDF, i removed the extra characters that remained during the string manipulation.

The above solution also uses the same way. The key idea is to distinguish between commas between different components and inside them. For that, I suggested the _comma_replacement(val) method which be called in a UDF. The above solution also utilizes the same method but using regxp_replace that can be more optimized.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

1. The DataFrame you have

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame([('id01', '{"P1":"1:0.01","P2":"3:0.03,4:0.04","P3":"3:0.03,4:0.04"}')], ['I', 'F'])
df.printSchema()
df.show(truncate=False)
```

You can see the schema and data are the same in your post.

```
root
 |-- I: string (nullable = true)
 |-- F: string (nullable = true)

+----+---------------------------------------------------------+
|I   |F                                                        |
+----+---------------------------------------------------------+
|id01|{"P1":"1:0.01","P2":"3:0.03,4:0.04","P3":"3:0.03,4:0.04"}|
+----+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

2. Process the string to distinguish sub-dicts

```
# remove '{' and '}'
df = df.withColumn('array', F.regexp_replace('F', r'\{', ''))
df = df.withColumn('array', F.regexp_replace('array', r'\}', ''))

# replace the comma with '#' between each sub-dict so we can split on them
df = df.withColumn('array', F.regexp_replace('array', '","', '"#"' ))
df = df.withColumn('array', F.split('array', '#'))
df.show(truncate=False)
```

Here's the middle results

```
+----+---------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|I   |F                                                        |array                                                      |
+----+---------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|id01|{"P1":"1:0.01","P2":"3:0.03,4:0.04","P3":"3:0.03,4:0.04"}|["P1":"1:0.01", "P2":"3:0.03,4:0.04", "P3":"3:0.03,4:0.04"]|
+----+---------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

3. Now generate one row for each sub-dict

```
# generate one row for each element int he array
df = df.withColumn('exploded', F.explode(df['array']))

# Need to distinguish ':' in the dict and in the value
df = df.withColumn('exploded', F.regexp_replace('exploded', '":"', '"#"' ))
df = df.withColumn('exploded', F.split('exploded', '#'))

# extract the name and value
df = df.withColumn('P', F.col('exploded')[0])
df = df.withColumn('N', F.col('exploded')[1])
df.select('I', 'exploded', 'P', 'N').show(truncate=False)
```

The final output:

```
+----+-----------------------+----+---------------+
|I   |exploded               |P   |N              |
+----+-----------------------+----+---------------+
|id01|["P1", "1:0.01"]       |"P1"|"1:0.01"       |
|id01|["P2", "3:0.03,4:0.04"]|"P2"|"3:0.03,4:0.04"|
|id01|["P3", "3:0.03,4:0.04"]|"P3"|"3:0.03,4:0.04"|
+----+-----------------------+----+---------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is very similar to what I already put as the answer.

Comment: it doesn't use `udf`, which should be faster in general.

Comment: what if F.col('exploded') is NULL and F.col('exploded')[0] and F.col('exploded')[1] are not valid?

Comment: Such special cases can be handled with `regexp_replace` etc. `udf` needs to do the similar things as well.

Comment: Thanks. Would you please share how do you handle these kind of corner cases?

Comment: Could you give some example with null?

Comment: I mean F.col('exploded') value is NULL then F.col('exploded')[0]  will not error? or if F.col('exploded') length is 1 then F.col('exploded')[1] will not error?

Comment: If there's a NULL in the array, `explode` puts the NULL together with "P3".
So this: `["P1":"1:0.01", "P2":"3:0.03,4:0.04", "P3":"3:0.03,4:0.04", null]` becomes `"P3"|"3:0.03,4:0.04", null`. You'll have to handle the extra null there.

Comment: So it means we cannot do anything at the access step (e.g. F.col('exploded')[0]) and if the value is not available there will be error. If it was returning NULL then it will be great but error is not :D

Comment: I think it can. it's just that F.col('exploded')[1] returns `"3:0.03,4:0.04", null` now. But it'll better to have some data to talk with.

Comment: Actually I am doing some unit testing and want to consider the corner cases. For example, let say we have {"P1":"","P2":"3:0.03,4:0.04","P3":"3:0.03,4:0.04"}. for "P1" the string value is empty. I am also testing this with my code and will let you know what is happening, shortly.

Comment: This should be no problem, empty string is still a string.