# Spark(Pyspark) - How to convert Dataframe String column to dataframe multiple columns

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a below pyspark `DataFrame[recoms: string]` where the `recoms` column value is of string type. Each row represent a string here.

```
+--------------------+
|         recoms     |
+--------------------+
|{"a":"1","b":"5",..}|
|{"a":"2","b":"4",..}|
|{"a":"3","b":"9",..}|
+--------------------+
```

The rows above doesn't have a defined schema to use the from_json method.So i'm looking for alternate options here. How do I convert or split to multi-value dataframe column as below using pyspark sql functions. In the above table all the values left to `:` would dataframe column name and right to `:` would be row values.

```
+--------+---+
|    a   | b |
+--------+---+
|    1   |  5|
|    2   |  4|
|    3   |  9|
+--------+---+
```

I tried explode sql function 
`df.select(explode("recoms")).show()` and getting the below error.

`org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'explode(true_recoms)' due to data type mismatch: input to function explode should be array or map type, not string;;`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pyspark: explode json in column to multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51070251/pyspark-explode-json-in-column-to-multiple-columns)

Comment: Not really but very close. The answers provided there have a schema defined for the conversion. For my use case, I want to convert it in a schema-less way, i.e; without defining any schemas.

Comment: Will all the rows have same schema ? If so, we can try to get schema dynamically and use it over all the rows.

Comment: @Barro could you please check my answer which is schema less and I hope solve your issue .

Comment: Do the rows come directly from a JSONlines file? If so, you can use `spark.read.json` which will infer the schema automatically for you.

Comment: @OliverW. The rows come from kafka topic. The string column in the table referred had dynamic key and values. I just want to convert the key as column name and value as the values for column name.

Comment: @Suresh yes all the rows have same schema, I'm reading the string column that I showed in the table above from kafka topics. Is there a way to infer schema dynamically from string column? All I want to do is, from string column just convert the key as column name and value as the values for column name.

Comment: Check if this helps, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41107835/pyspark-parse-a-column-of-json-strings