# Transform json content in new columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pyspark

I have a dataset with `semi structured data`, I need to transform the `json` inside the `content` column in other columns.

Data:

```
    customer    flow    session timestamp               content
1   C1000   F1000   S2000   2019-12-16 13:59:58+00:00   {'name': ''}
2   C1000   F1000   S2000   2019-12-16 13:59:59+00:00   {'name': 'joao'}
4   C1000   F1000   S2000   2019-12-16 13:59:59+00:00   {'cpf': '733.600.420-26'}
```

The desired result looks like this:

```
+--------+-----+-------+-------------------+-------------------+-----+--------------+------------------+
|customer|flow |session|first_answer_dt    |last_answer_dt     |name |cpf           |delivery_confirmed|
+--------+-----+-------+-------------------+-------------------+-----+--------------+------------------+
|C1000   |F1000|S1000  |2019-12-16T13:59:58|2019-12-16T14:00:01|maria|305.584.960-40|sim               |
|C1000   |F1000|S2000  |2019-12-16T13:59:59|2019-12-16T14:00:00|joao |733.600.420-26|não               |
+--------+-----+-------+-------------------+-------------------+-----+--------------+------------------+
```

I'm searching in the internet, but it is hard to find some solution to this case.

Comment: related: [Pyspark: explode json in column to multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51070251/pyspark-explode-json-in-column-to-multiple-columns) for pyspark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can try `.join` and `pd.Series`

```
#use eval if your json is a string.
df1 = df.join(df['content'].map(eval).apply(pd.Series)).drop('content',axis=1)
#or if not string
df1 = df.join(df['content'].apply(pd.Series)).drop('content',axis=1)
print(df1)
  customer   flow session                 timestamp  name             cpf
0    C1000  F1000   S2000 2019-12-16 13:59:58+00:00                   NaN
1    C1000  F1000   S2000 2019-12-16 13:59:59+00:00  joao             NaN
2    C1000  F1000   S2000 2019-12-16 13:59:59+00:00   NaN  733.600.420-26
```

Comment: Hey, thanks. 
But I didn't understand the function of eval.

Comment: @RafaelLima it's to turn your raw strings into objects

Comment: in my case, this column is an object.


customer  object

 flow  object
session  object
timestamp datetime64[ns, UTC]
content object
dtype: object