# how to parse array of json into multiple columns - Pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I have a table like this below

| job_id | job_score | job_status | job_details |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| job_a | 234.5 | Active | [{"xyz": "","abc": "","def": "avg_xyz_value","ghi":"","jkl":"XYZDatafeed110m2211V1","mno": {"uvw":"XYZ_TAG_30201.PV"},"pqr": 0.26911367973842457,"stu": 0.1234},{"xyz": "","abc": "","def": "avg_xyz_value","ghi":"","jkl":"XYZDatafeed110m2211V1","mno": {"uvw":"XYZ_TAG_30202.PV"},"pqr": 0.16911367973842457,"stu": 0.3623},{"xyz": "","abc": "","def": "avg_xyz_value","ghi":"","jkl":"XYZDatafeed110m2211V1","mno": {"uvw":"XYZ_TAG_30203.PV"},"pqr": 0.36911367973842457,"stu": 0.2345},{"xyz": "","abc": "","def": "avg_xyz_value","ghi":"","jkl":"XYZDatafeed110m2211V1","mno": {"uvw":"XYZ_TAG_30204.PV"},"pqr": 0.46911367973842457,"stu": 0.9345},{"xyz": "","abc": "","def": "avg_xyz_value","ghi":"","jkl":"XYZDatafeed110m2211V1","mno": {"uvw":"XYZ_TAG_30201.PV"},"pqr": 0.56911367973842457,"stu": 0.5345} |

and I want to parse the data into multiple columns like this

| job_id | job_score | job_status | uvw | stu |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XYZDatafeed110m2211V1 | 234.5 | Active | XYZ_TAG_30201.PV | 0.1234 |
| XYZDatafeed110m2211V1 | 234.5 | Active | XYZ_TAG_30202.PV | 0.3623 |
| XYZDatafeed110m2211V1 | 234.5 | Active | XYZ_TAG_30203.PV | 0.2345 |
| XYZDatafeed110m2211V1 | 234.5 | Active | XYZ_TAG_30204.PV | 0.9345 |
| XYZDatafeed110m2211V1 | 234.5 | Active | XYZ_TAG_30204.PV | 0.5345 |

How can I do this in pyspark?

Would much appreciate your help!

Comment: is database [virtual column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) suitable here?

Comment: no.. sorry :( @Hicomputer

Comment: Please add sample input ? looks like your input is broken

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pyspark: explode json in column to multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51070251/pyspark-explode-json-in-column-to-multiple-columns)

Answer (score 0):

Check below code.

```
df
.withColumn(
    "job_details",
    expr("
      transform(
        from_json(
          job_details,
          'array<map<string,string>>'
        ),
        e -> named_struct(
              'job_id', e['jkl'],
              'job_score',job_score,
              'job_status',job_status,
              'uvw', from_json(e['mno'],'map<string,string>')['uvw'],
              'stu',e['stu']
            )
      )
    ")
)
.selectExpr("inline(job_details)")
.show(false)
```

```
+---------------------+---------+----------+----------------+------+
|job_id               |job_score|job_status|uvw             |stu   |
+---------------------+---------+----------+----------------+------+
|XYZDatafeed110m2211V1|234.5    |Active    |XYZ_TAG_30201.PV|0.1234|
|XYZDatafeed110m2211V1|234.5    |Active    |XYZ_TAG_30202.PV|0.3623|
|XYZDatafeed110m2211V1|234.5    |Active    |XYZ_TAG_30203.PV|0.2345|
|XYZDatafeed110m2211V1|234.5    |Active    |XYZ_TAG_30204.PV|0.9345|
|XYZDatafeed110m2211V1|234.5    |Active    |XYZ_TAG_30201.PV|0.5345|
+---------------------+---------+----------+----------------+------+
```